# How to read NFC Tag and call Webservice in Android

Tags: java, android, nfc

I'm now developing an android application with the `NFC concept` . In that application I need to pick my application if I swipe the NFC card and if I select my application my application must start calling webservice.

when it comes to my problem, If suppose my app crashed ,when I swipe the card next time ,the option to choose the application doesn't open .Instead,my application directly launched and couldn't call the webservice data.

**On the whole.I'm getting last page when it crashed .But I need to open as fresh**

I came to know that I need to make changes in `OnResume() and OnNewIntent()`.

I used ,
 In OnResume()

```
    super.onResume();
         mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent,      mNdefExchangeFilters, null);
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
NdefMessage[] msgs = getNdefMessages(getIntent());

byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();


//Toast.makeText(this, new String(payload), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Student=new String(payload);



if(Student.equals(rakesh)
{
new Webservice.execute("");  // Calling SOAP Webservice
}
```

But,I can't find any changes with my problem .and **one more thing that the problem will be resolve after I just open and close an another NFC project**

Please help.

Comment: Share a little bit more of your code like where you are calling WS , when you are calling it ...what code lies in `OnResume()` ..

Comment: I've updated my question .please look at that and reply me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah ! I got the solution .I forget a simple thing that I left calling onStop() method and my problem was,when my application stops(when Crashed).It runs in background as the previous activity.

I just tried the following,

```
   public void onStop()
{
super.onStop();
this.finish();
}
```

This may be helpful to others.

Thanks..